# Import lists of numbers in python from excel sheets with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm an absolute beginner with python, and I want to use it mainly for producing 2D plots with matplotlib starting from excel data.

Let's suppose I have an excel sheet with the numbers 10, 20, 30, 40 in the first four rows of the first column; I want to create a python list with these numbers.

I was trying:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('filepathname')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

list = []
for row in range(0,4):
   list.append(str(sheet.cell(row,0)))
```

in order to create a list with such values... but when I try to print it, I get

```
['number:10.0', 'number:20.0', 'number:30.0', 'number:40.0']
```

how can I do, instead, to get something like

```
['10.0', '20.0', '30.0', '40.0']
```

so that it is recognized as a list of pure numbers? Is there a way for doing it still using xlrd?

Comment: You don't sound a beginner at all! Esp. an "absolute" one! There's no shame in asking a question, even a simple one and even if you are an expert in Python! Anyone can have any question at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('filepathname')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

list = []
for row in range(0,4):
    # Remove str(...) if you want the values as floats.
    list.append(str(sheet.cell(row,0).value))  # Changed this line
```

Reference: https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/cell.html

Particularly, you want the `Cell.value` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.cell(row, col).value
```

will provide the value in the cell.